# Loopback - PostgreSQL: How to do row level locking?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm using Loopback with PostgresSQL. I've check Loopback documents but seem there is no instruction to do row level locking. I've try use transaction like this:

- Process A begin transaction, select a Trade with that transaction, then wait for 10 seconds. So it should lock that row in 10 seconds.
- Process B run 2 seconds after process A, also begin transaction and select the same Trade.

What I expect is process B should not be able to select that row before 10 seconds expired, but it can.

Consider this script:

```
const wait = s => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, s * 1000));

async function test(id, processName) {
  const { Trade } = app.models;
  const transaction = await Trade.beginTransaction({});

  console.log(`Process ${processName} - start`);
  const trade = await Trade.findOne({ where: { id }, transaction });
  if (trade) {
    console.log(`Process ${processName} - trade found`);
  }

  await wait(10);
  transaction.commit();
  console.log(`Process ${processName} - finished`);
}

test('1809004512', 'A');
// Wait 2 seconds before calling process B
wait(2).then(() => test('1809004512', 'B'));
```

Here is the log:

```
Process A - start
Process A - trade found

// 2 seconds waiting

Process B - start
Process B - trade found

// 8 seconds waiting

Process A - finished
Process B - finished
```

What I expect is, if the row is locked the right way, `Process B - trade found` should be printed after `Process A - finished`

What should I do? Please help